# Parse tweets Twitter API

Tags: api, post, twitter, get

I am trying to get the latest tweets from a twitter user. This is what I've got so far:

```
$string = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=Cristiano&include_entities=true");

$json_=json_decode($string,true);
```

This is my error message:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: When I click on the link above, I get `{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}`

Comment: you are using api1. they upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want/need to migrate to the latest version of the API: `1.1`. More information about the deprecation of version `1` can be found at the [Twitter API Calendar of Changes documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/calendar).

Next, you'll need to authenticate to the API prior before having access to it. More information about *that* can be found at the [Twitter API Authentication & Authorization page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth).

Comment: I have registreredme as a Twitter Developer now. I have signature basestring, an authorization header and cURL command (QAuth tool).

I have updated my API call
$string = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=Cristiano&include_entities=true"); 

How do authenticate to the API prior? I am writting my script in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth), the PHP library, should help you get started. If that answers your question, please select an answer.

Comment: I want to parse the tweets without making the user login. I want my server to make an API call to get the tweets, and then I want my server to "extract" the important paramters and create a JSON output.

I have googled, but I can only find examples where the user generates a token by login in...

Is there a way to get tweets without making the user login? All the tweets are from public twitter pages.

Comment: http://pastie.org/8367896

I that the way to get tweets without making the user login? I'll try it now!

Comment: "message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215"

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=Cristiano&include_entities=true) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in XX line 22

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: My code: http://pastie.org/8368135
My error message: http://pastie.org/8368140

I have all the developer keys.

Answer (score -1):

POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
User-Agent: My Twitter App v1.0.23
Authorization: Basic eHZ6MWV2RlM0d0VFUFRHRUZQSEJvZzpMOHFxOVBaeVJn
                     NmllS0dFS2hab2xHQzB2SldMdzhpRUo4OERSZHlPZw==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 29
Accept-Encoding: gzip

grant_type=client_credentials

That is the required HTTP POST request. How do I sent it using PHP?